# Convert nested list into dataframe

Tags: r, reshape2

I saw similar questions answered in stackoverflow, but I couldn't find the way to fit my specific situation, so I open a new one.

My goal is to convert a nested list like this:

```
a:list of 2
..$ time: num[1:5] 1 2 3 4 5
..$ int: num[1:5] 6 7 8 9 0

b:list of 2
..$ time: num[1:5] 1 2 3 4 5
..$ int: num[1:5] 6 7 8 9 0
```

into a dataframe like this:

```
Name time int
a    1    6
a    2    7
.
.
.
b    1    6
...
```

I tried to use `melt` in `reshape2` and I got time and int as the values in one column(L2). Something like this:

```
Value L2    L1
1     time  a
2     time  a
.
.
.
6     int   a
.
.
.
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use `ldply` from `plyr` package

```
library(plyr)
ldply(lst, data.frame, .id = "Name")
```

Taking dummy data from @SymbolixAU 's answer, you have the output as

```
#  Name time int
#1   a    1   5
#2   a    2   6
#3   a    3   7
#4   b    1   1
#5   b    2   2
#6   b    3   3
#7   b    4   4
```

Comment: It seems ldply works for my dataset. I don't get mislabeled time and int pairs.

Answer (score 5):

`rbindlist` from the `data.table` package should do

```
## some dummy data
lst <- list(a = list(time = c(1,2,3),
                     int = c(5,6,7)),
            b = list(time = c(1,2,3,4),
                     int = c(1,2,3,4)))

# str(lst)
# List of 2
# $ a:List of 2
# ..$ time: num [1:3] 1 2 3
# ..$ int : num [1:3] 5 6 7
# $ b:List of 2
# ..$ time: num [1:4] 1 2 3 4
# ..$ int : num [1:4] 1 2 3 4

library(data.table)

rbindlist(lst, idcol = "id")

#     id time int
# 1:  a    1   5
# 2:  a    2   6
# 3:  a    3   7
# 4:  b    1   1
# 5:  b    2   2
# 6:  b    3   3
# 7:  b    4   4
```

And if you want it back as a `data.frame`

```
df <- rbindlist(lst, idcol = "id")
setDF(df)

# str(df)
# 'data.frame': 7 obs. of  3 variables:
# $ id  : chr  "a" "a" "a" "b" ...
# $ time: num  1 2 3 1 2 3 4
# $ int : num  5 6 7 1 2 3 4
```

Comment: Thanks for your help. But this way, I lost the first level list name info as a column in my dataframe. For example, my "a" and "b" is gone and I can't tell which time is for a or b.

Comment: @juanwang - `rbindlist(lst,idcol="id")` - there is an `idcol` argument that will take care of that.

Comment: thanks for the reminder @thelatemail - I've updated the answer to incorporate the `idcol`

Comment: I just found out if I add idcol="id", then since I have fewer "id" than "time" values, the "id" values got repeated used so I got the wrong assignment of "id" for my data.